# Database first database projects

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, database-project

I have been working on a new project for a little while and already have the Database in sqlServer2008.
I would like to put the DB into a database project to make installation better.

Is there a way to import an exisiting database into a DB project?

Thanks,

EDIT:
This is in VisualStudio 2010 btw... oops!

Comment: What type of database do you want to import, that will be a big help.

Comment: it is a sql database? it does say that above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start a new SQL Server 2008 database project.

In the Schema View window, choose the command to `Import Database Objects And Settings`. From there, you'll be asked to choose a database from Server Explorer, or you can browse, provide a connection string, etc.

**If this is not what you're looking for**, please leave a comment, and we can get it sorted out!

[image]

[image]